# Output all product attribute values on catalog page

Tags: theme, catalog, template

On the catalog grid page, I want to output all filterable attribute values for each product. For example: If the price is filterable in the layered navigation, the attribute value associated with the product would be output (£0.00 - £999.99, £20,000 and above, etc).

I have the start of something but can't work out how to filter by product only and grab the value:

```
            $_productId = $_product->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
             foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                echo $attribute->getAttributeCode();

              }
```

This just seems to output every attribute code on every product.

This is how I think it should be represented in terrible pseudocode:

```
get allProductAttributes
foreach allProductAttributes as attribute
    if attribute->isFilterable
        echo attribute->getAttributeValue
    endif
endforeach
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**First idea** : Change all the attributes, so "Used in Product Listing" is the same as "Use In Layered Navigation", then you have only the attributes in the product which are filterable.

**Second idea**: Write an observer and change the attributes which are selected.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$collection
   ->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
   ->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
   ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
   ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
   ->addIsFilterableFilter();
```

This way you get the filterable attributes. And with the following code, you get the ones from the product listing:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$collection
   ->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
   ->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
   ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
   ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
   ->addIsFilterableFilter();
   ->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.used_in_product_listing', array('gt' => 0));
```

Then you can loop over the ones from the losting, remove them all with `$collection->removeAttributeToSelect()` and afterwards you add all the filterable attributes.

But I recommend the first idea, then you don't have to code.